# dynamic parameter not working in a Put method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm migrating a solution from asp net to asp net core. When I tested this method

```
 [HttpPut, Route("SearchPrices")]
    public dynamic SearchPrices(dynamic data)
    {
        var list = from ma in db.Materials
                   select new
                   {
                       ma.MaterialID,
                       ma.MaterialTypeID,
                       ma.StatusID,
                       ma.Horsepower,
                       ma.MaterialPrice
                   };

        list = list.OrderBy(s => s.MaterialID);

        string filterString = data.filterString;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterString))
        {
            list = list.Where(ma => new[] {
                ma.MaterialID,
                ma.MaterialPrice.ToString(),
                ma.MaterialTypeID
            }.Any(c => c.Contains(filterString)));
        }

        dynamic sort = data.sort;
        string column = sort.column;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
        {
            bool reverse = sort.reverse;
            list = list.OrderByColumn(column, reverse);
        }
        return FilterByColumn(list, data);
    }
```

I receive a parameter with something like

```
ValueKind = Object : "{"filterString":"","options":[],"skipNumber":0,"takeNumber":50,"sort":{"column":"","reverse":false}}"
```

In which I cant make it work like it used to before, it throws a error when it tries to resolve "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain a definition for 'filterString''".

I've already tried some solutions to deserialize, but they didn't work.

Comment: You likely want to use Json.NET, instead of System.Text.Json. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project) for how to do that.